# Нету стилей css в php

Tags: css

http://robloxseller.ru/pages/account//account.php?id=1 
Стили подключены, можно чекнуть в коде, НО они не применяются, а если переходить напрямую вписав в адрес. строку, то стили есть, в чем проблема?

Comment: у вас в подключенных css находится html код , для чего так ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не нужно подключать стили и т.п. относительными путями. Вместо:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../dist/styles/header.css">
```

Пишите абсолютный путь от корня:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/dist/styles/header.css">
```

Двойной слеш `//` как подпапка определяется.